# Spectral norm and its relation with size of the network

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

The spectral norm can be understood as an alternative measure of the size of a network i.e. number of nodes.
http://konect.uni-koblenz.de/statistics/snorm

$| \lambda_1[\mathbf A] | = \left\| \mathbf A \right\|_2$

what is the proof for this

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you asking for a proof that $\|A\|$ coincides with the largest eigenvalue, or are you asking for a proof that $\|A\|$ "is an alternative measure of the size of a network"?

Comment: The spectral norm can be understood as an alternative measure of the size of a network - i did not understand this statement